# Is it true that $1-x=\exp(-x+O(y))$ if $x^2=O(y)$ and $0\le x\le 1$ by Taylor's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion

I wonder whether it is true that $1-x=\exp(-x+O(y))$ if $x^2=O(y)$ and $0\le x\le 1$? If not, how if we know $x=o(1)$ additionally?

**Revision:** We can assume $x=x(z)$ and $y=y(z)$ and $z$ is an asymptotic parameter going to infinity. So $x^2=O(y)$ means there exits a constant $C$ s.t. $x^2\le Cy$ for all $z$. $x=o(1)$ means for $z$ tending to $\infty$, $x$ tends to 0.

My feeling is that $\exp(-x)=1-x+\frac{\eta^2}{2}$ for some $\eta\in(0,x)$ by Taylor's Theorem, then use $y\le \exp(y)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\eta^2\le x^2=O(y)$, then one might represent $\exp(-x)-O(y)$ by $\exp(-x+O(y))$? But I am not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: well $x^2=O(y)$ imposes nothing on $y$, it can be quite big, so I don't see how the formula can be true in all cases.

Comment: @zwim $y$ could be very big. But in the exponent, we only require $O(y)$, so it can be very small.

Comment: The question is not clear. Presumably, $O(y)$ means some function of $x$ which is bounded by $y(x)$ when $x$ goes where exactly??

Comment: I made some revision to make it clear. We can assume $x,y$ both depends on some parameter $z$ and $O(\cdots)$ refers to $z\to\infty$.